# Why does C# use a different Naming convention?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, uml, conventions

I started working with C# recently and I noticed that the convention seems to be that the variables start with a capital letter along with the methods.

Is this the only language that does this and why?
For instance:

```
Page Page = new Page();
Page.Action();
```

In other languages, you'd see instead:

```
Page page = new Page();
page.action();
```

There are other examples of this that are confusing since I've worked a lot with UML, Ruby, C++ and Java.

My question is, why does C# do it this way when other languages do not?

#### Edit

> Other Stack Overflow users are noting that C# does not follow this convention, this was just a mistake on my part.

Comment: That's not the C# convention...

Comment: I have never seen that convention used.  Ever.

Comment: You may have gotten confused because properties are PascalCase. Variables are camelCase according to convention.

Comment: I think so too... I miss Ruby ^^

Comment: I suppose someone could close this question?

Comment: Would be a shame to close it. How about editing it with regard to what you've learned. Last few places I've been at could really do with a refresh on standard naming.

Comment: For reasons I don't know (I don't know why some of my ex-coworkers developed this convention), I have also seen this in C# code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well actually, no: the convention in C# is for camelCased variable (and field) names, and PascalCase methods:

```
Page page = new Page();
page.Action();
```

Comment: PascalCase is for public methods, properties, and events

Comment: Ok, I guess the code I saw so far was just messy, then. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

No, this is fairly non-standard C# code.  The .Net Framework Design guidelines in section 2.6 recomend the use of camel casing for local variable names.

- [http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/articles/361363.aspx](http://web.archive.org/web/20120801053215/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/26/361363.aspx)

Comment: This is a very good article about why C# is the way it is.  I personally love the standard he list here.  At my job they have a horrific naming convention of l_s_SomeString for a local string.  I hate underscores.

Answer (score 7):

Public members use `PascalCase`, private members use `camelCase`.

I think that this makes it clearer which methods support a class versus which methods define a class.

```
public class Foo
{
    private Bar bar;
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }

    public void DoFoo()
    {
        makeFoo();
    }

    private void makeFoo()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the Microsoft Naming Guidelines makeFoo() should be  named MakeFoo(). There is no difference in the casing for methods, properties, and events depending on their scope. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(VS.71).aspx

Comment: You're right.  The published guidelines only concern themselves with publicly exposed members, and leave internal guidelines to the implementer.  In C#, I have only ever seen camelCase for private methods, but I suppose it's not a "standard" per se. Like all other conventions for private members, it's up to the implementer to define. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Every set of C# conventions I've written or used would specify camel case for variables, so:

```
Page page = new Page();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

Not sure where you've seen Pascal case used, but it's certainly not something inherent to, or standard for, C#.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in C# typically don't start with an uppercase letter (though that's obviously up to the developer's own implementation). What you're probably confused about is the concept of a [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d(VS.71).aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1). Properties in C# are used syntactically like variables (in that they can be retrieved or assigned, rather than just executed like a function), but can encapsulate business logic on both operations.

To answer a broader part of your question, though, both properties and methods/functions do typically start with an uppercase letter according to the [Microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

PascalCase was a convention at Microsoft long before .NET. (In the Win32 API etc.)

A convention also makes sense to use within a single environment. .NET being a comprehensive environment on its own, and Microsoft-the-company another, there's really no point to adopting someone else's.

Also, I strongly doubt UML has a naming convention or that even the idea of UML having a naming convention makes sense. UML models your software, and should follow the convention of that software.

Answer (score 2):

Public = PascalCase, I only tend to use camelCase for private fields, and parameter arguments.

Read this [coding standard though](http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/gemrcsharpcs.pdf) easily searchable on google, not a bad place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out a lot about what conventions should be adopted by using the two following tools.

FxCop: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx

StyleCop: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis